# Проблема кодировки русских символов при записи в базу данных MySQL скриптом php

Tags: php, mysql

При записи в базу данных вручную (phpmyadmin) русских букв  все хорошо, а при записи через скрипт крокозябры.
Все файлы в кодировке utf8, база и поля utf8_general_ci.
Заранее спасибо))

SET NAMES cp1251; пробовал.

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else {

        $result = mysqli_query($connect,
                        "insert into requests(date, name, phone, email)
                        values('$date', '$name','$phone','$email')");
                        echo('вроде  скрипт записи рабоает');
    }
    if ($result == true){
        echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
    }
    else{
        echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
    }   echo $result;
}
```

Comment: уточните, какая кодировка используется для страницы, на которой заполняются данные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас в примере функция `mysqli_connect` создает соединение. И я не уверен, что `mysql_query` может использовать ресурс созданные расширением `mysql i`.

Функции расширения будут удалены из будущих версий PHP, так как в языке уже давно используют PDO.

Если желание использовать `mysqli` всё еще есть, посмотрите примеры на англоязычном Stackoverflow - например по [этой ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903302/mysqli-connection-and-query)